# Ionic / Angular hide or shuffle part of url

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

there are 3 paths in app-routing.module.ts where I pass parameters, one example below.

[image]

Is there any way to hide or shuffle part of url direct in app-routing.module.ts? And have the result like this.

http:localhost/edit-channel

or

http:localhost/edit-channel/jhsdjhySDNsdsdbSMKDHsodyoiwhemnzkdhSDsndmhoicyoiwherM

Answer (score 0):

I chose to create an objectable to not pass the data via URL.

This way the URL is clear.

[image]

Compoment A call the component B and send the data to objectable service.

```
this._EditChannelService.EditChannel(_id, title, description, visibility);
```

Objectable service

```
export class EditChannelService {
    private _ID = new BehaviorSubject<any>("");
    private _Title = new BehaviorSubject<any>("");
    private _Description = new BehaviorSubject<any>("");
    private _Visibility = new BehaviorSubject<any>("");

    get ID$() {
        return this._ID.asObservable();
    }

    get Title$() {
        return this._Title.asObservable();
    }

    get Description$() {
        return this._Description.asObservable();
    }

    get Visibility$() {
        return this._Visibility.asObservable();
    }

    constructor(
        public _Router: Router,
    ) {
    }

    EditChannel(id: any, title: any, description: any, visibility: any) {
        this._ID.next(id);
        this._Title.next(title);
        this._Description.next(description);
        this._Visibility.next(visibility);

        this._Router.navigate(['edit-channel']);
    }
}
```

Component B get the data on init

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._EditChannelService.ID$.subscribe(data => {
      this.editChannelForm.get('_id').setValue(data);
    }).unsubscribe;

    this._EditChannelService.Title$.subscribe(data => {
      this.editChannelForm.get('title').setValue(data);
    }).unsubscribe;

    this._EditChannelService.Description$.subscribe(data => {
      this.editChannelForm.get('description').setValue(data);
    }).unsubscribe;

    this._EditChannelService.Visibility$.subscribe(data => {
      this.editChannelForm.get('visibility').setValue(data);
    }).unsubscribe;
  }
```